# Short term dataplans for tablets with no talk options in the UK?

Tags: uk, data-plans, mobile-operators

When going to the UK with a smartphone (with limited or expensive data on my contract) and a tablet computer I might opt for a sim in my tablet which only allows data.
As I will not be that long in the UK, I guess it will be 2 weeks, at most 4 weeks, it should be a short term plan or prepaid option.
My phone will be available for receiving calls and the odd call I have to make, so calls and messages do not need to be part of the contract.

I expect to visit places where wifi is available but it is often of such a poor quality that I prefer to use the 3G or 4G networks, for which I need a direct connection.

Are these kind of plans available for non-UK residents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where you are going, you might first want to decide which UK network to use. In rural areas, coverage can be quite patchy and choosing a network with good coverage at your location will be relevant.

I got a 70GB EE pay as you go card last week for 20£. It was a matter of about 10 minutes in an EE shop to buy and activate the SIM. Other (virtual) operators will have similar deals. There is no requirement to be a UK resident.

Comment: (+1) The Ofcom broadband and mobile coverage checker might be a good place to start https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms-and-internet/advice-for-consumers/advice/ofcom-checker

Answer (score 1):

[Smarty mobile](https://smarty.co.uk/data-sim) seems like a good option. They offer no contract, data-only sims with no credit checks either.

Here are the prices:

[image: prices]

To be on the safe side, I would go with the 15GB option as you may run out if you choose the 2GB one. I have no affiliation with Smarty mobile.